# MySQL Workbench Error: Couldn't connect the SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, mysql-workbench

Full Error:  [image]

I am trying to establish a connection to a database instance in AWS EC2. I've spent hours looking at all the posts that exist on Stack Overflow and many other places related to this but nothing works for me.

I am able to use my .pem key to establish a connection successfully through PuTTY on my Windows 10 machine. I also am able to connect and use the database in dbForge Studio and DataGrip but I get this error when I use MySQL Workbench (I am trying to transition to the free software). I think this is something related to the key. Is there anything else required to do with the key after I downloaded it from AWS? Or does MySQL Workbench require anything different than dbForge or DataGrip?

Do I need to change the key format or add it to /.ssh folder or something along those lines? These are the tips I got from other answers but unfortunately, nothing worked for me. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: for that to work youu need some preparation see https://linuxhint.com/connect-aws-rds-mysql-workbench/

Comment: @nbk thanks for the reply. I already went through this process and still gives me the same error.

Comment: try first with putty to reach the server, if  that works you have a chance with workbench. it is nearly imposible to say why it doesn't work. i would check with wireshark, what already happens. but putty shpuld give you a hint

Comment: @nbk That's the thing, I can connect through PuTTY, dbForge, and DataGrip. Just not MySQL Workbench.

Comment: then you have some some parameters wrong see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8138/190821 if this clears things up

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm the MYSQL hostname that you provided is local IP address 127.0.0.1 and the port number 3306. Because you're connecting over ssh and accessing the localhost inside the machine. And make sure to give proper read permission for your SSH pem file like `chmod 400 my_test_key.pem`. For your reference here I'm attaching a read.

https://towardsdatascience.com/running-mysql-databases-on-aws-ec2-a-tutorial-for-beginners-4301faa0c247

[image]